# Packaging Code + property file

Tags: java, packaging

I have packages.. a, b and c in my java application. I have a resources folder set for my application and it contains packages x, y, z.

I need to package files in a,b and property file in x as a jar. 
I am using net beans 6.5. How do I achieve this!

Comment: which version of netbeans are you on ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Netbeans specific, but you can add the files to the jar via the command line:

```
jar uf jar-file input-file(s)
```

More details [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/jar/update.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet here would be to edit the nb-build.xml (or build.xml if you created the project from scratch)  file and add an ant target (-pre-jar) that copies the files to the build dir where it will get added by the jar target.